# arisexylightboxlite static method error

Tags: php

I am using a php module in my joomla site called: Ari Sexy Lightbox Lite. I was running on php 5.3 and had to go to 5.6.

However... Since this php upgrade i am getting two errors in my page.

```
Deprecated: Non-static method AriJSONHelper::encode() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/deb25878n3/domains/hang-on-run.nl/public_html/plugins/content/arisexylightboxlite/arisexylightboxlite.php on line 93

Deprecated: Non-static method AriJSONHelper::_getJSONHandler() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/deb25878n3/domains/hang-on-run.nl/public_html/plugins/content/arisexylightboxlite/arisexylightboxlite/kernel/Web/JSON/class.JSONHelper.php on line 21
```

I tried to fix this myself but my php knowledge is way to rusty...

I really hope that someone can help solve this.

This is the code itself:

```
<?php
/*
 * ARI Sexy Lightbox Lite Joomla! 1.5 plugin
 *
 * @package     ARI Sexy Lightbox Lite 
 * @version     1.0.0
 * @author      ARI Soft
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2009 www.ari-soft.com. All rights reserved
 * @license     GNU/GPL (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html)
 * 
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');
jimport('joomla.filter.filterinput');

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/arisexylightboxlite/kernel/class.AriKernel.php';

AriKernel::import('Web.JSON.JSONHelper');

class plgContentArisexylightboxlite extends JPlugin
{
    /*
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct(&$subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    }

    function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params)
    {
        $this->prepareContent($article, 'arisexylightboxlite');
    }

    function onPrepareContent(&$article, &$params, $limitstart)
    {
        $this->prepareContent($article);
    }

    function prepareContent($article, $folder = '')
    {
        static $loaded;

        if ($loaded)
            return ;

        $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();

        $plgParams = $this->params;
        $rel = $plgParams->get('opt_find', 'sexylightbox');
        $loadAssets = $plgParams->get('loadAssets', 'auto');
        if ($loadAssets == 'auto' && (empty($article->text) || !preg_match('/<[^>]*rel=("|\')?' . $rel . '(\[|"|\'| |\/)/i', $article->text)))
            return ;

        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $baseUri = JURI::root(true) . '/plugins/content/' . ($folder ? $folder . '/' : '') . 'arisexylightboxlite/js/';
        $loadJQuery = (bool)$plgParams->get('includeJQuery', false);
        $noConflict = (bool)$plgParams->get('noConflict', true);

        if ($loadJQuery)
        {
            $loadJQueryMethod = $plgParams->get('loadJQueryMethod', 'google_cdn');

            if ($loadJQueryMethod == 'local')
            {
                if (J3_0)
                    JHtml::_('jquery.framework', $noConflict);
                else
                    $document->addScript($baseUri . 'jquery.min.js');
            }
            else
            {
                $document->addScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js');
            }

            if ($noConflict)
            {
                if (!J3_0 || $loadJQueryMethod != 'local')
                    $document->addScript($baseUri . 'jquery.noconflict.js');
            }           
        }

        $document->addScript($baseUri . 'jquery.easing.js');
        $document->addScript($baseUri . 'jquery.sexylightbox.min.js');

        $document->addStyleSheet($baseUri . 'sexylightbox.css');

        $jsOptions = $this->getOptions($folder);
        $document->addScriptDeclaration(
            sprintf('jQuery(document).ready(function(){ SexyLightbox.initialize(%s); });',
                $jsOptions ? AriJSONHelper::encode($jsOptions) : ''));

        $loaded = true;
    }

    function getOptions($folder = '')
    {
        $defOptions = array(
            'find' => 'sexylightbox',
            'zIndex' => 32000,
            'color' => 'black',
            'emergefrom' => 'top',
            'showDuration' => 200,
            'closeDuration' => 400,
            'moveDuration' => 1000,
            'moveEffect' => 'easeInOutBack',
            'resizeDuration' => 1000,
            'resizeEffect' => 'easeInOutBack',
            'shake' => array(
                'distance' => 10,
                'duration' => 100,
                'loops' => 2,
                'transition' => 'easeInOutBack'
            )
        );
        $options = $this->getParamOptions($defOptions);

        $options['dir'] = str_replace(' ', '%20', JURI::root(true) . '/plugins/content/' . ($folder ? $folder . '/' : '') . 'arisexylightboxlite/js/sexyimages');

        return $options;
    }

    function getParamOptions($defOptions, $prefix = 'opt_')
    {
        $plgParams = $this->params;
        $options = array();
        $filter = JFilterInput::getInstance(); 
        foreach ($defOptions as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_array($value))
            {
                $subOptions = $this->getParamOptions($value, $prefix . $key . '_');
                if (count($subOptions) > 0)
                    $options[$key] = $subOptions;
            }
            else
            {
                $paramValue = $plgParams->get($prefix . $key, $value);
                if ($paramValue !== $value)
                {
                    $paramValue = $filter->clean($paramValue, gettype($value));
                    if ($paramValue !== $value)
                        $options[$key] = $paramValue;
                }
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```